# Android application which can calculate the days between two dates

Tags: android, project-management, calendar

I am seeking an Android application which can take two dates and calculate the relevant events between them including (but not exclusive to)

- Weekdays
- Weekend Days
- Total Days
- Bank Holidays / National Holidays

Primarily used for forecasting invoices, project management and holidays.

**Caveat**:  I am based in the United Kingdom

Comment: It might be useful to know which country/countries you are interested in as the national holidays differ so much around the world.